# Only allow space in the middle of first name and surname

Tags: javascript, input, text

Trying to find a solution for an issue we are having.

When a user enters a value in to a input text box we do not want the user to be able to enter a space at the beginning or after the last word

We are able to do this at the start with the following code however we cannot work out how to apply this to the end whilst still allowing a space in the middle.

```
    $(function() {
    $('body').on('keydown', '#test', function(e) {
     console.log(this.value);
    if (e.which === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
     return false;
     }  
     });
     });
```

Allowed

"Bob Smith"

Not Allowed

" Bob Smith"

"Bob Smith "

" Bob Smith "

Comment: From usability point of view, it's a really bad idea to validate as the user is typing. Remove the spaces on the server when you receive the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just use javascript Trim method, it removes the whitespaces before and after the input,

so if you have something like " Bob Smith     ",

it returns you "Bob Smith"

```
var str = "       Bob Smith!        ";
console.log(str.trim());
```

// output "Bob Smith"

Answer (score 0):

What if you just check that the user's selection isn't at the end?

```
if (e.which === 32 && (e.target.selectionStart === 0 || e.target.selectionStart === this.value.length && this.value.includes(" "))) {}
```

That'll check if the selection is at the end of the input AND that it already contains a space (i.e., the space you want to allow between the two names).

The other answers using the `.trim()` method would work on a `"keyup"` event, after the value has been updated, but not on `"keydown"` (as is shown in your question).

Answer (score 0):

use trim

```
" a ".trim()
will be -> "a"
```

if you want to know whether the user has inserted any space char in front or end of field simply compare lengths after triming

```
" a ".trim().length === " a ".length
false

"a".trim().length === "a".length
true
```

Answer (score 0):

One mundane solution could be to pass the value to a regex and get the bits you need at each keydown event:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/0tvvpezt/2/

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
     var cT = e.currentTarget,
         temp;
     cT.value = (temp = cT.value.match(/\w+(?:\s+)?(?:\w+)?/gi), temp && temp[0] || "");
},false)
```

I allowed multiple space between first and last name on purpose change it if you want

Answer (score 0):

For this case you need regular expressions.
I think the following will help (you may find the better option).

If you need to get rid off spaces before and after the input you could use `trim()`.

```js
function isCorrect(input) {

  const regex = /^[A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]*$/i;

  if (input.match(regex)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const strs = [
  "John Doi",
  "Helen  J",
  " One more",
  "Singlename",
  "Jake Cham "
];

function test() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  strs.forEach((e, i, arr)=> {
    const li = document.createElement('p');
    li.innerText = `Element #${i} - ${isCorrect(e)}`;
    body.appendChild(li);
  });
}

window.onload = () => {
  test();
  console.log('document loaded');
};
```